# In "A plethora of", should I use "A" always?

Tags: word-usage, articles, indefinite-articles, noun-phrases, premodifiers

> - A plethora of problems
> - Plethora of problems

Are both ok? Because in many articles, "A" is not  written.

Comment: Can you quote an example of an article that uses wording like "plethora of problems"?

Comment: The definite article is also used where appropriate.

Comment: @sumelic "A plethora of problems" uses wording like "plethora of problems".

Comment: @Kris: Sorry, I don't understand the point of your comment. Could you elaborate on how is it meant to be helpful? In the context of this question, it seems to me that Yu-Yeo is contrasting cases where "plethora of X" is preceded by the indefinite article *a* with cases where it isn't. I'm asking for examples of the second usage. "A plethora of problems" is not an example of this.

Comment: @sumelic The wording of your earlier comment needed as much of an explanation and defence as  the latter comment. It could have been better.

Comment: Why the hasty close votes?

Answer (score 1):

No, you must use the article — and under most circumstances, the indefinite one. That’s because this is simply how such premodifying phrases used as noun quantifiers are always constructed. They must all follow this formula:

> ***a(n)*** + NOUN (singular) + ***of*** + NOUN (either singular or plural)

It no more makes sense to use *plethora of X* without an indefinite article preceding it than it does any of these formulations:

- a lot of
- a glut of
- a surfeit of
- a surplus of
- a deluge of
- a flood of
- an inundation of
- a torrent of
- a spate of
- an abundance of
- an overabundance of
- an excess of
- a plenitude of
- a superfluity of
- a nimiety of
- a profusion of
- a share of
- a parcel of
- a ration of
- a pile of
- a heap of
- a load of
- a volume of
- a mountain of
- a ton of
- a sea of
- a truckload of
- a buttload of

Those all mean something rather like the quantifier *many* (or *too many*) if it’s a plural noun following, and something rather like the quantifier *much* (or *too much*) if it’s a mass noun following.

Please be aware that those examples are taken from a wide variety of registers. They are therefore *not* meant to be identical to the point of all being freely interchangeable within the same work. Some are common, others are rare.

Occasionally these can take a definite article when the sense requires it, as in

> The resulting surfeit of entrants overwhelmed their sign-up desk.

Be advised that words like *plethora* and *surfeit* are “fancy” ones that belong to a far higher register than one normally employs in casual communications.

Comment: You left out 'shitton'

Comment: @Mitch I believe the SI unit is a metric f`ckload.

Comment: The range of determiners permissible with these is interesting to me. Some seem to be amenable to a "countable" determiner (*several spates of conversation later*, *a dozen heaps of trash*, but not **several gluts* or **three profusions*). And on the other hand I think "lot of" can *only* take the singular indefinite determiner; anything else changes the meaning (which may be why "alot" is creeping into the lexicon).

Comment: @1006a *We'll be having the whole lot of you over for drinks afterwards.*

Comment: @tchrist But that's a different meaning than *We'll be having a lot of you over for drinks* or even *We'll be having a whole lot of you over for drinks*. Think of Monty Python's glutton ordering "the lot" versus ordinary gluttons ordering "a lot" at a restaurant. With most of these, you can say "there are a plethora/surplus/heap/mountain/truckload/ of problems. . . . The plethora/surplus/heap/mountain/truckload of problems we previously mentioned..." But "There are a lot of problems. . . . The lot of problems we previously mentioned..." just sounds wrong.